# Delphi XE2 could not create output file

Tags: delphi, windows-7, delphi-xe2

Win 7 64 bit, Delphi XE2 Target 32 bit. When I switch from Debug configuration to Release, I get

```
[DCC Fatal Error] uADStanIntf.pas(1016): F2039 Could not create output file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\da-soft\AnyDAC for Delphi\Source\uADStanIntf.dcu'
```

I don't see any difference in the options settings, Library and Browsing paths are the same. The path should be

```
'C:\Program Files (x86)\da-soft\AnyDAC for Delphi\DCU\D16\uADStanIntf.dcu'
```

Comment: The research was digging through all the configuration settings. The question was helpful to me, asking it got a solution. Maybe it will be useful to others, I cannot control that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to compile source files from a third party library that has been installed to the program files directory, which is read only to non-administrators.

You should not be compiling source files from the program files directory, and should certainly not be outputting there. You should copy the source files to a directory inside your development tree. In other words to a directory which is writable. Obviously you'll need to update the search path.

You should also set your output directory to the default for XE2 which is:

```
.\$(Platform)\$(Config)
```

This will output to folders like `Win32\Debug` when the placeholders are expanded.

Apply this setting to the all configurations target in the project options, so that it can be inherited.

Perhaps you don't want to compile these source files at all, and would prefer to use supplied .dcu files. In that case add the directory containing the .dcu files to your search path.

Comment: I'm not intentionally trying to compile ithe third party .dcu, but it appears that is the case. I don't know why.

Comment: You must have the source folder in your search path, or the files in your project

Comment: Which source folder? By search path, do you mean browsing path or library path. The 3rd party source and dcu paths are in both.

Comment: Mike, don't put directories in your search path that you don't want to compile. For source code that you don't want to compile, use the *browsing path*. Keep the source code and the compiled DCUs separate. Only the DCUs should be on the search path.

Comment: When I say you must, I mean that must be so for you to have this error. But you should not have set it up that way.

Comment: Rob & David - I'm still unclear on what y'all are calling the search path. I took the path to the 3rd party dcus & source files out of the library path and left them in the browsing path. Now neither of the configs find the dcus.

Comment: Put the path to the dcus in the search path

Comment: What's the search path?

Comment: The light finally cam on. I was looking in the wrong options.